# Record stereo audio from two Bluetooth headsets

Tags: bluetooth, esp32, audio

I've been playing with Arduino for a few years, but I'm new to Bluetooth and streaming audio.

I'd like to develop (or assemble or buy) a device for recording stereo audio from a pair of Bluetooth headsets to a lossless file format on a micro SD card. I'm thinking this would be great for recording a podcast on the go with two people.

I'm guessing an ESP32 or similar could relatively easily record mono audio to an SD card.

Questions:

1. Any recommendations on libraries and/or tutorials that could be used to piece together audio recording from a Bluetooth headset mic to lossless audio file on micro SD card? I'm thinking at least this first step should be relatively straightforward. :)
2. Any suggestions on how to integrate two stream of mono audio from two Bluetooth headset mics in order to combine to a single stereo audio file (using the streams as left and right channel)? I think this would require two Bluetooth receivers, and streaming the audio from each to a third processor for combining and saving the streams to a single stereo file. But again I'm interested in libraries, frameworks, etc.

Thanks so much!!

Comment: you basically need a real computer for this, not an MCU. it's easy to combine two mono tracks into a stereo file in audacity, so just record the pod in mono on each phone and export.

Comment: I realized this later in the day, a Raspberry Pi or similar computing platform would be needed. I was thinking there might be an external audio processing board I could use, but better to just use R Pi with USB audio interface or similar. 

I don't want to record separately and combine because I don't want to have to manually allign the audio clips every time.